# A little confused with gmail imap folders not showing

Tags: catalina, mail.app, gmail, imap

so im on catalina 10.15.7 and running Mail version 13.4  I use to be able to see my imap folders when i would click the show button and they would expand below the corresponding accoun,like for instance, how my icloud folders(saved, stamps, etc) are showing under icloud.  Is there a way to get the folders for the 2 gmail accounts to show?  Attached is a pic of my mail app and the gmail setting for 1 of the gmail accounts showing that i have it set for impap.  Tks much

[image: mail app]
[image: gmail]

Comment: I am a little confused by the question whose title suggest a problem with iCloud, but the detail seems to be about gmail - is that right?  If so, what folders were you expecting to see below gmail (which you don't show in the screenshot!)?

Comment: sorry - i meant to put imap.  the gmail screen shot shows what folders i have selected to show in imap.  when i click the show/hide button for the gmail accounts i do not see the corresponding folders.  I referenced icloud as an example also of folders checked and that i see.  Arent i suppose to see checked folders from gmail too?

Comment: the word "Hide" is visible because i clicked "Show" to show the folders and left my cursor there to make the word Hide visible for the screenshot.  There are no folders showing.  "Hide" is visible meaning that i have clicked "Show" and if i want to "Hide" what would be showing, to click "Hide".

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I am using Mail 14.0 where the look and feel is slightly different and I do see the default folders under Google. What happens if you add a folder to gmail? I wonder if the default ones will then magically appear. A problem for Apple is that Google mail is not standard IMAP (e.g.has labels as well as folders) and does need special treatment. We need a comment/answer from someone running 10.15.7.

Comment: I added a folder.  None followed. I also inched and rechecked google options. No different. Rebuilt mailboxes too. Not sure what to try next.

Comment: suppose to be unchecked and rechecked gmail folder options from gmail.  deleted and added account again too.